# Azure SQL DW: How can I create an external table with calculated columns to split DateTime

Tags: azure-synapse, external-tables

I am receiving an error trying to create an External Table with a calculated column based on DOB column for the purpose of splitting the date into three columns (Year, Month, Day).

Example Columns of dbo.Persons:

```
   | FirstName | LastName | DOB | DOBYear | DOBMonth | DOBDay |
```

SQL Code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].Person
(
FirstName VARCHAR(250), 
LastName VARCHAR(250), 
DOB datetimeoffset,
DOBYear DATE AS DATEPART("yyyy", DOB)
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION='.....' 
,   DATA_SOURCE = ....
,   FILE_FORMAT = ....
,   REJECT_TYPE = VALUE
,   REJECT_VALUE = 0
)
;
```

However I can never get it to excute as I get this error below:

```
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Parse error at line: 28, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'.
```

How can I resolve this? I have the theory that perhaps this is not supported via external table? If there is a way to implement are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse external tables do not support computed columns.  You could however create a view over the top to serve the same purpose, eg

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_person
AS
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    DOB,
    DATEPART( yyyy, DOB ) AS DOBYear
FROM dbo.Person
```

NB `DATEPART` parameters do not take quotes, so I have corrected your example.

Comment: Thanks for the info!